# Second order linear differential equation determining patterns in a solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi could anyone help me solve this problem.

Given the following second order linear differential equations, determine whether its solutions are bounded (it means that $y(x)$ is either periodic or has a limit 0 as x tends to infinity) without having to solve the differential equations.

$$y''+10y'+89y=0 \\ y''-10y'+89y=0$$

I do not know how to begin with this.
I believe it has something to do with finding the sum and product of the roots.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, we have:

$$m^2+10 m+89=0 \implies m_1 = -5 -8i,~ m_2 = -5 + 8i$$

For the second, we have:

$$m^2-10 m+89=0 \implies m_1 = 5 -8i, ~m_2 = 5 + 8i$$

Now, what do the signs of the real part tell you?

Comment: Oh so does it means to say if the real part is a negative value, then the solution tend to 0 as x tends to infinity?

Comment: Oops: I missed your comment to my comment about our goals...our addictions!